# What's the composition of Actinobacteria's hyphae?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

I'd like to know which chemical compounds form hyphae in Actinobacteria. Is it the same structure of the cell wall?

Thank you

Comment: Can you specify this a bit more? You want to know the single building blocks of the hyphae?

Comment: I understood that cells grow in tubular structures that form the hyphae, but i'd like to know how cells build this structure. Which are the chemical compounds that cells secrete to bulid the hyphae?
Is it clear?